# Initialize redux form controls with state to props

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

Packages used

```
"react-redux": "^5.0.6",
"redux-form": "^8.2.5",
"react": "^16.4.2",
```

Here is the component

```
class EditProfileForm extends Component {
 return(
       <div>
       <Field name="firstName" component="input" >
       </div>
      )
}

EditProfileForm = reduxForm({    
    form: 'EditProfileForm'
})(EditProfileForm);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  initialValues: state.profile.firstName
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditProfileForm);
```

**Issue facing:**

```
Invariant Violation: You must pass a component to the function returned by connect. Instead received {"displayName":"ReduxForm","defaultProps":{"touchOnBlur":true,"touchOnChange":false,"persistentSubmitErrors":false,"destroyOnUnmount":true,"enableReinitialize":true,"keepDirtyOnReinitialize":false,"updateUnregisteredFields":false,"pure":true,"forceUnregisterOnUnmount":false,"submitAsSideEffect":false,"form":"EditProfileForm"}}
```

Comment: if you have just started using forms in your app, I would suggest you to use [formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your component

1) You are using a class component, which implies it needs to extend **Component** (which you have done) with a **render method** (you have missed this) in it, which will return the JSX markups.

```
class EditProfileForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Field name="firstName" component="input"/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

2)  **initialValues** prop needs to be an object not a value

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  initialValues: state.profile
});
```

In case you were trying to create a Functional Component, here is the solution

```
let EditProfileForm = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Field name="firstName" component="input"/>
    </div>
  );
};

EditProfileForm = reduxForm({
  form: 'EditProfileForm'
})(EditProfileForm);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  initialValues: state.profile
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditProfileForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

your component is not correct, please have this example

```
class EditProfileForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <Field name="firstName" component="input"/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```